# Python Socket Receive Large Amount of Data

Tags: python, sockets

When I try to receive larger amounts of data it gets cut off and I have to press enter to get the rest of the data. At first I was able to increase it a little bit but it still won't receive all of it. As you can see I have increased the buffer on the conn.recv() but it still doesn't get all of the data. It cuts it off at a certain point. I have to press enter on my raw_input in order to receive the rest of the data. Is there anyway I can get all of the data at once? Here's the code.

```
port = 7777
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind(('0.0.0.0', port))
sock.listen(1)
print ("Listening on port: "+str(port))
while 1:
    conn, sock_addr = sock.accept()
    print "accepted connection from", sock_addr
    while 1:
        command = raw_input('shell> ')
        conn.send(command)
        data = conn.recv(8000)
        if not data: break
        print data,
    conn.close()
```

Answer (score 165, accepted):

TCP/IP is a *stream-based* protocol, not a *message-based* protocol.  There's no guarantee that every `send()` call by one peer results in a single `recv()` call by the other peer receiving the exact data sent—it might receive the data piece-meal, split across multiple `recv()` calls, due to packet fragmentation.

You need to define your own message-based protocol on top of TCP in order to differentiate message boundaries.  Then, to read a message, you continue to call `recv()` until you've read an entire message or an error occurs.

One simple way of sending a message is to prefix each message with its length.  Then to read a message, you first read the length, then you read that many bytes.  Here's how you might do that:

```
def send_msg(sock, msg):
    # Prefix each message with a 4-byte length (network byte order)
    msg = struct.pack('>I', len(msg)) + msg
    sock.sendall(msg)

def recv_msg(sock):
    # Read message length and unpack it into an integer
    raw_msglen = recvall(sock, 4)
    if not raw_msglen:
        return None
    msglen = struct.unpack('>I', raw_msglen)[0]
    # Read the message data
    return recvall(sock, msglen)

def recvall(sock, n):
    # Helper function to recv n bytes or return None if EOF is hit
    data = bytearray()
    while len(data) < n:
        packet = sock.recv(n - len(data))
        if not packet:
            return None
        data.extend(packet)
    return data
```

Then you can use the `send_msg` and `recv_msg` functions to send and receive whole messages, and they won't have any problems with packets being split or coalesced on the network level.

Comment: I am not sure if I am understanding this completely. I understand the what's supposed to be happening but I cant't seem to be getting it. I am getting `Exception: Socket EOF trying to recv 4 bytes`

I am using the following: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=AvdN5RyW

Comment: @user2585107: Try the updated version, which uses a `return None` instead of raising an exception when the stream ends.

Comment: shouldn't the `packet` be `.decode()`ed before adding it to `data` or `recv()` can receive both bytes and strings?

Comment: Thanks bro, was going bald pulling my hair out :D

Comment: Why doesn't `recv` block until it has received the amount of data specified?

Comment: @Jean: Most of the time the application doesn't even know how much data it will be receiving in advance (e.g. consider an HTTP GET request). Applications will typically call `recv()` with a large buffer and then process however much data they received. If the server blocked the `recv()` call until it received a full buffer, it might be waiting forever if a request was smaller than a buffer. The server does have to know when it's received a full vs. partial request, which depends on the protocol being used, which is outside the scope of `recv()`.  With HTTP, a request is terminated by \r\n\r\n.

Comment: The line `data += packet` can make receiving VERY slow for large messages. It's much better to use `data = bytearray()` and then `data.extend(packet)`.

Comment: @StanKriventsov: That's an excellent point, I've updated the sample with that.  I would guess that the Python runtime (of course there are many different runtime implementations) would have an optimization for this case to avoid the copy and perform the extension internally when the buffer's refcount is 1, but it's certainly not guaranteed and we shouldn't rely on that.

Comment: I certainly haven't tried every Python runtime for this task, but at least none of the versions that I use have this optimization.

Comment: Thanks in advance for the answer! However, I am getting such error: "
BlockingIOError: [Errno 35] Resource temporarily unavailable" in "packet = sock.recv(n - len(data))"

Answer (score 36):

You can use it as: `data = recvall(sock)`

```
def recvall(sock):
    BUFF_SIZE = 4096 # 4 KiB
    data = b''
    while True:
        part = sock.recv(BUFF_SIZE)
        data += part
        if len(part) < BUFF_SIZE:
            # either 0 or end of data
            break
    return data
```

Comment: This works for detection of "End of File", but not for keeping a connection and detecting the end of a message. "End of File" will only be reached if the peeer closes its part of the socket, or at least half-closes it.

Comment: If the string received is less than 4096 chars, it will loop again and re-check for more data using `sock.recv()`. This will hang since there isn't any more data is coming in. If the length of `part` is less than that of the `RECV_BUFFER`, then the code can safely break out of the loop.

Comment: @JadedTuna, doesn't seem to be fixed. The line "part = sock.recv(BUFF_SIZE)" seems to be a blocking call, thus execution hangs at this line once the full message has been received.

Comment: This code should be fixed as
if len(part) < BUFF_SIZE:
            # either 0 or end of data
            break

Comment: This seems to wrongly assume that one send on one end of a TCP socket corresponds to one receive of sent number of bytes on the other end (see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30655169/3002584) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1806965/3002584)). Thus, even when a client sends exactly 4kb with one `send`, server might get the first, say, 1kb at the first `recv`, which would lead the `while` to break.

Answer (score 23):

The accepted answer is fine but it will be really slow with big files -string is an immutable class this means more objects are created every time you use the `+` sign, using `list` as a stack structure will be more efficient.

This should work better

```
while True: 
    chunk = s.recv(10000)
    if not chunk: 
        break
    fragments.append(chunk)

print "".join(fragments)
```

Comment: this is exactly what sped up my large binary file downloads by around 30-50X... thanks

Answer (score 21):

Most of the answers describe some sort of `recvall()` method. If your bottleneck when receiving data is creating the byte array in a `for` loop, I benchmarked three approaches of allocating the received data in the `recvall()` method:

Byte string method:

```
arr = b''
while len(arr) < msg_len:
    arr += sock.recv(max_msg_size)
```

List method:

```
fragments = []
while True: 
    chunk = sock.recv(max_msg_size)
    if not chunk: 
        break
    fragments.append(chunk)
arr = b''.join(fragments)
```

Pre-allocated `bytearray` method:

```
arr = bytearray(msg_len)
pos = 0
while pos < msg_len:
    arr[pos:pos+max_msg_size] = sock.recv(max_msg_size)
    pos += max_msg_size
```

Results:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You may need to call conn.recv() multiple times to receive all the data.  Calling it a single time is not guaranteed to bring in all the data that was sent, due to the fact that TCP streams don't maintain frame boundaries (i.e. they only work as a stream of raw bytes, not a structured stream of messages).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17664544/one-recv-gets-tow-or-more-send-in-python-sockets/17664559#17664559) for another description of the issue.

Note that this means you need some way of knowing when you have received all of the data.  If the sender will always send exactly 8000 bytes, you could count the number of bytes you have received so far and subtract that from 8000 to know how many are left to receive; if the data is variable-sized, there are various other methods that can be used, such as having the sender send a number-of-bytes header before sending the message, or if it's ASCII text that is being sent you could look for a newline or NUL character.

Answer (score 5):

**Disclaimer:** There are very rare cases in which you really need to do this. If possible use an existing application layer protocol or define your own eg. precede each message with a fixed length integer indicating the length of data that follows or terminate each message with a '\n' character. (Adam Rosenfield's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17668009/7406945) does a really good job at explaining that)

With that said, there is a way to read all of the data available on a socket. However, it is a bad idea to rely on this kind of communication as it introduces the risk of loosing data. Use this solution with extreme caution and only after reading the explanation below.

```
def recvall(sock):
    BUFF_SIZE = 4096
    data = bytearray()
    while True:
        packet = sock.recv(BUFF_SIZE)
        if not packet:  # Important!!
            break
        data.extend(packet)
    return data
```

Now the `if not packet:` line is absolutely critical!
Many answers here suggested using a condition like <s>`if len(packet) < BUFF_SIZE:`</s> which is broken and will most likely cause you to close your connection prematurely and loose data. It wrongly assumes that one send on one end of a TCP socket corresponds to one receive of sent number of bytes on the other end. It does not. **There is a very good chance that `sock.recv(BUFF_SIZE)` will return a chunk smaller than `BUFF_SIZE` even if there's still data waiting to be received.** There is a good explanation of the issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30655002/socket-programming-recv-is-not-receiving-data-correctly/30655169#30655169) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708835/python-socket-receive-incoming-packets-always-have-a-different-size/1806965#1806965).

By using the above solution **you are still risking data loss** if the other end of the connection is writing data slower than you are reading. You may just simply consume all data on your end and exit when more is on the way. There are ways around it that require the use of concurrent programming, but that's another topic of its own.

Answer (score 2):

A variation using a generator function (which I consider more pythonic):

```
def recvall(sock, buffer_size=4096):
    buf = sock.recv(buffer_size)
    while buf:
        yield buf
        if len(buf) < buffer_size: break
        buf = sock.recv(buffer_size)
# ...
with socket.create_connection((host, port)) as sock:
    sock.sendall(command)
    response = b''.join(recvall(sock))
```

Comment: That one does not appear to work if the response is smaller than the buffer size.

Comment: @Shadur, that's interesting, what happens when you try it? can you please share the code to reproduce the issue? As written, `recvall` should yield the contents of each buffer received regardless of the size as long as it's not empty.

Comment: Judging by debug statements added, it inhales the entire response in the first chunk, then hangs waiting for the next chunk. The 'chunck' answer below has the same problem, I wound up fixing it with a second test to see if chunck's length was less than the buffer size. I'll test whether that fixes your solution as well. -- EDIT: It did.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using Serialization

```
from socket import *
from json import dumps, loads

def recvall(conn):
    data = ""
    while True:
    try:
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        return json.loads(data)
    except ValueError:
        continue

def sendall(conn):
    conn.sendall(json.dumps(data))
```

NOTE: If you want to shara a file using code above you need to encode / decode it into base64

Answer (score 1):

I think this question has been pretty well answered, but I just wanted to add a method using Python 3.8 and the new assignment expression (walrus operator) since it is stylistically simple.

```
import socket

host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 31337
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host,port))
s.listen()
con, addr = s.accept()
msg_list = []

while (walrus_msg := con.recv(3)) != b'\r\n':
    msg_list.append(walrus_msg)

print(msg_list)
```

In this case, 3 bytes are received from the socket and immediately assigned to `walrus_msg`. Once the socket receives a `b'\r\n'` it breaks the loop. `walrus_msg` are added to a `msg_list` and printed after the loop breaks. This script is basic but was tested and works with a telnet session.

NOTE: The parenthesis around the `(walrus_msg := con.recv(3))` are needed. Without this, `while walrus_msg := con.recv(3) != b'\r\n':` evaluates `walrus_msg` to `True` instead of the actual data on the socket.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying Adam Rosenfield's code:

```
import sys


def send_msg(sock, msg):
    size_of_package = sys.getsizeof(msg)
    package = str(size_of_package)+":"+ msg #Create our package size,":",message
    sock.sendall(package)

def recv_msg(sock):
    try:
        header = sock.recv(2)#Magic, small number to begin with.
        while ":" not in header:
            header += sock.recv(2) #Keep looping, picking up two bytes each time

        size_of_package, separator, message_fragment = header.partition(":")
        message = sock.recv(int(size_of_package))
        full_message = message_fragment + message
        return full_message

    except OverflowError:
        return "OverflowError."
    except:
        print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
        raise
```

I would, however, heavily encourage using the original approach.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who's looking for an answer in cases where you don't know the length of the packet prior.
Here's a simple solution that reads 4096 bytes at a time and stops when less than 4096 bytes were received. However, it will not work in cases where the total length of the packet received is exactly 4096 bytes - then it will call `recv()` again and hang.

```
def recvall(sock):
    data = b''
    bufsize = 4096
    while True:
        packet = sock.recv(bufsize)
        data += packet
        if len(packet) < bufsize:
            break
    return data
```

Answer (score 0):

This code reads 1024*32(=32768) bytes in 32 iterations from the buffer which is received from Server in socket programming-python:

```
jsonString = bytearray()

for _ in range(32):

    packet = clisocket.recv(1024)
    if not packet:
       break
    jsonString.extend(packet)
```

Data resides in jsonString variable

Answer (score 0):

Plain and simple:

```
data = b''
while True:
    data_chunk = client_socket.recv(1024)
    if data_chunk:
         data+=data_chunk
    else:
         break
```