# TypeError in socket, when pickle

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, pickle

I'm trying to write a client-server program where server receives the requests for a database records, or files, and sends it back. Everything was working just fine until I used the pickle function to send data from client to server,

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 551, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "server.py", line 71, in run
    data = pickle.loads(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1381, in loads
    file = StringIO(str)
TypeError: expected read buffer, NoneType found
```

When I send data from server to client, there is no problem. I worked like this for a few weeks but when there is about 50 exceptions, the server program closes.

### client.py file:

```
import socket
import sys
import time
import pickle
import struct
def recvall(sock, n):
    # Helper function to recv n bytes or return None if EOF is hit
    data = ''
    while len(data) < n:
        packet = sock.recv(n - len(data))
        if not packet:
            return None
        data += packet
    return data

def recv_msg(sock):
    # Read message length and unpack it into an integer
    raw_msglen = recvall(sock, 4)
    if not raw_msglen:
        return None
    msglen = struct.unpack('>I', raw_msglen)[0]
    # Read the message data
    return recvall(sock, msglen)


def sending(msg):
    host = 'localhost'
    port = 50000
    size = 1024
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((host,port))
    lenght = len(msg)
    if lenght>0:
        msg = pickle.dumps(msg)
        msg = struct.pack('>I', len(msg)) + msg
        s.sendall(msg)
        print 'sended string lenght: '+str(lenght)
    else:
        s.send('nothing sended')
    data = recv_msg(s)
    lenght2 = len(data)
    print data
    print 'received string lenght: '+str(lenght2)
    #sys.stdout.write(data)
    s.close()

while 1:
    msg = raw_input('Input:')
    sending(msg)
```

### server.py:

```
class Client(threading.Thread): 
    def __init__(self,(client,address)): 
        threading.Thread.__init__(self) 
        self.client = client 
        self.address = address 
        self.size = 1024 

    def run(self): 
        running = 1 
        while running: 
            sock = self.client
            data = self.recv_msg(sock)
            data = pickle.loads(data)
            if data:
                msg = struct.pack('>I', len(data)) + data
                self.client.sendall(msg)
            else: 
                self.client.close() 
                running = 0 

    def recv_msg(self, sock):
        # Read message length and unpack it into an integer
        raw_msglen = self.recvall(sock, 4)
        if not raw_msglen:
            return None
        msglen = struct.unpack('>I', raw_msglen)[0]
        # Read the message data
        return self.recvall(sock, msglen)

    def recvall(self, sock, n):
        # Helper function to recv n bytes or return None if EOF is hit
        data = ''
        while len(data) < n:
            packet = sock.recv(n - len(data))
            if not packet:
                return None
            data += packet
        return data
```

In previous version I puted the pickle function from server to client, and it worked fine, no problems, but now I started to write it from the beginning to find the problem, but I didn't. 
The recv_msg method was found here:
[Python Socket Receive Large Amount of Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17667903/python-socket-receive-large-amount-of-data)

Comment: Yes, it did. Sorry, that I didn't answered immidiately, but I'm new in here. Now it looks like it's a simple change, but on my level it was a great help, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `recv_msg` method returns `None` when EOF is reached, and you pass that `None` to `pickle.loads`, which is an error.

To fix the problem, place the call to `pickle.loads()` *after* the EOF-check:

```
        data = self.recv_msg(sock)
        if data is not None:
            data = pickle.loads(data)
            msg = struct.pack('>I', len(data)) + data
            self.client.sendall(msg)
        else: 
            self.client.close() 
            running = 0
```

Comment: You may want to change `if is not None:` to `if data is not None:`