# Sending images via tcp

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I am having issues with pictures over python sockets. The image is not being sent out not fully. This is how it gets received

**The client**

```
elif data == 'screenshot':

    screen = os.system("screencapture screen.jpg")

    file = open('screen.jpg', 'rb')
    prop = file.read()      
    file.close()

    s.sendall( prop )
```

**The server**

```
data = c.recv(999999999)

img = open('image.jpg', 'wb')
img.write( data )
```

What is happening is the original file is say 800 kb and then the data written is 300kb. Is there a way of getting the full image to show up and not half or 20% of the image.

[image: Original file] This is the image i want copied

[image: New file not everything is copied] What gets copied!!!

Comment: How do you know that you've received all the data?

Comment: The problem is that you assume that `recv` will get you all data at once. Possible duplicate of [Python Socket Receive Large Amount of Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17667903/python-socket-receive-large-amount-of-data)