# In TCP recv() receive only 4 kb

Tags: python, tcp

I am trying to send and receive file over TCP with Python. But recv() method get only 4KB of files, rest is discarded. How can ı get all bytes in file?

Comment: The rest is not discarded. You have to loop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Socket Receive Large Amount of Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17667903/python-socket-receive-large-amount-of-data)

Answer (score 1):

recv is a low-level interface.  It will read "bufsize" (defaults to 4k) bytes at a time.  You need to keep calling it until it returns zero bytes back to you to get all the data.

See here for more:
https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html#using-a-socket