Socket setup and handling partial messages in FIX
In my Python initiator application, my socket receives fix messages in the following manner:
socket_local = socket.create_connection((address, port))
socket_local.settimeout(0.001)

chunk_size=2048

    def listen_message():
        mybytes = b''
        while True:
            try:

                chunk = socket_local.recv(chunk_size)
                if not chunk:
                    break

                mybytes+= chunk

                if len(chunk)<chunk_size:
                    break
   return mybytes

While evaluating incoming packages after mybytes is completed and listen_message returned I noticed, I am getting partial messages in some packets, such as:
**packet1(1 complete + 1 partial)=** "b'8=FIX.4.2\\x019=79\\x0135=A\\x0134=1\\x0149=TESTSENDER\\x0152=20240110-01:07:28.124\\x0156=TESTACCEPTOR\\x0198=0\\x01108=10\\x01141=Y\\x0110=138\\x018=FIX.4.2\\x019=79\\x0135=A\\x0134=1\\x0149=TESTSENDER\\x0152=20240110-01:07:28.124\\x0156=TESTA'

**packet2(1 partial)=** b'CCEPTOR\\x0198=0\\x01108=10\\x01141=Y\\x0110=138\\x01'


Messages are for the sake of example only, it happens mostly on long execution reports when there is an inflow of messages.

I wonder if there is something wrong in my socket_recv setup and looking for ways to prevent partial messages, instead handling them in an expensive completion function. Messages might not be sequential, the remaining part can come 5 messages after.

TCP is not message-oriented, it is a stream-oriented protocol. Higher-level protocols are responsible for any message framing or message boundaries. I don't know anything about the FIX protocol but there is probably a python library out there that correctly handles it for you.

Yeah there is quickfix, but I am more into know what I am doing and learn, maybe optimize.

Tag 9 contains length of the message. Everything after that length of bytes should go into the next message.

What if the partial message is cut just in between the tag9 so that the parser don't know what the tag9 is until it finds the other part? I have been looking into pcaps for these partials and it shows as reassembled TCP segments with a full complete message. Somehow, pcap processor is able to figure out which message belongs to what, that is why I am looking more into socket based explanations.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17667903/python-socket-receive-large-amount-of-data ?
